# Why can't I import the Google Cloud client library in Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I'm working in Python 2.7.10.

i'm just trying to run `from google.cloud import storage`, but I get `ImportError: No module named google.cloud`.

google-cloud appears to be installed correctly. `pip install google-cloud` returns `Requirement already satisfied: google-cloud in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (0.34.0)`, and `pip show google-cloud` returns:

```
Name: google-cloud
Version: 0.34.0
Summary: API Client library for Google Cloud
Home-page: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python
Author: Google Cloud Platform
Author-email: googleapis-publisher@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

EDIT: thanks to Duy below for reminding me about the next step.
Running `pip install google-cloud-storage` throws a bunch of errors:

```
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7b/7c/c9386b82a25115cccf1903441bba3cbadcfae7b678a20167347fa8ded34c/pyasn1-0.4.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
protobuf 3.6.1 has requirement six>=1.9, but you'll have six 1.4.1 which is incompatible.
google-api-core 1.7.0 has requirement six>=1.10.0, but you'll have six 1.4.1 which is incompatible.
google-auth 1.6.2 has requirement six>=1.9.0, but you'll have six 1.4.1 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: setuptools, protobuf, googleapis-common-protos, urllib3, certifi, chardet, idna, requests, futures, pyasn1, rsa, pyasn1-modules, cachetools, google-auth, google-api-core, google-cloud-core, google-resumable-media, google-cloud-storage
  Found existing installation: setuptools 18.5
    Uninstalling setuptools-18.5:
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', '/private/var/folders/_h/5cqnls4d2jxckyjk70267q_c0000gp/T/pip-uninstall-ZBmwkH/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/_h/5cqnls4d2jxckyjk70267q_c0000gp/T/pip-uninstall-ZBmwkH/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py', '/private/var/folders/_h/5cqnls4d2jxckyjk70267q_c0000gp/T/pip-uninstall-ZBmwkH/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/_h/5cqnls4d2jxckyjk70267q_c0000gp/T/pip-uninstall-ZBmwkH/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', '/private/var/folders/_h/5cqnls4d2jxckyjk70267q_c0000gp/T/pip-uninstall-ZBmwkH/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/_h/5cqnls4d2jxckyjk70267q_c0000gp/T/pip-uninstall-ZBmwkH/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc', '/private/var/folders/_h/5cqnls4d2jxckyjk70267q_c0000gp/T/pip-uninstall-ZBmwkH/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/_h/5cqnls4d2jxckyjk70267q_c0000gp/T/pip-uninstall-ZBmwkH/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', '/private/var/folders/_h/5cqnls4d2jxckyjk70267q_c0000gp/T/pip-uninstall-ZBmwkH/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/_h/5cqnls4d2jxckyjk70267q_c0000gp/T/pip-uninstall-ZBmwkH/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib'")]
```

I don't understand what the environment error is, and all my searches run down unhelpful rabbit holes.

Comment: Pip is telling you that you have packages that are tool old (not compatible) with google-cloud-storage. Add the upgrade option to pip: `pip install -U google-cloud-storage`. Pip will now upgrade `six` to a supported version provided that this upgrade does not conflict with other already installed packages.

Comment: @JohnHanley Using a dedicated environment worked, but I didn't understand why. I think it it must be because that allowed everything to get installed from scratch. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The [`google-cloud`](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud/) package is deprecated, you should uninstall it and install [`google-cloud-storage`](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud/) instead.

Comment: Thank you! See my edit, because that throws an environment issue. Do I need to uninstall google-cloud?

Comment: You should uninstall `google-cloud`, and then reinstall `google-cloud-storage`. The errors look unrelated, it seems like you might have `sudo pip installed` something by mistake, and don't have permissions to uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a python environment.

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv <your-env>
source <your-env>/bin/activate
<your-env>/bin/pip install google-cloud-python
```

Check here for more details about `virtualenv` https://cloud.google.com/python/setup

Comment: Ah, brilliant! Thank you, that seems to have done it. I understand why using an environment is helpful, but I don't understand why it was required in this case. Can you elaborate?

Comment: These isolated environments can have their own separate versions of Python packages, which allows you to isolate your projects dependencies from the dependencies of other projects. I recommend that you always use a per- project `virtualenv` when developing locally with Python.

Answer (score -1):

You forget to install `pip install google-cloud-storage`

Comment: Forgot to mention it at least. This is where things get really weird, sorry I forgot to include it in my main question. Let me update my post so that I have full access to formatting.