# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud'

Tags: python, google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-text-to-speech

I'm looking to use the Google "cloud text to speech" api, and I'm having the common problem of the module not being found. I've tried the solutions that most people have, only problem being that I use windows and most of the solutions are for mac or Linux (although this shouldn't be that big of an issue).

I ran the 'pip list' on the command line and here's what it returned:

```
google                    2.0.1
google-api-core           1.7.0
google-auth               1.6.3
google-cloud              0.34.0
google-cloud-texttospeech 0.4.0
googleapis-common-protos  1.5.8
```

And if this helps, this is what I have been running on the import statement (**this is also taken from google's tutorial**)

```
>> from google.cloud import texttospeech

from google.cloud import texttospeech
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud'
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named google.cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44397506/importerror-no-module-named-google-cloud)

Comment: For anyone on the duplicate, unless I'm not aware, you can't use sudo install on windows correct?

Comment: No, you can't use sudo. But you can use the relative command of windows. The concept is the same. The logic.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54247070/why-cant-i-import-the-google-cloud-client-library-in-python

Comment: Essentially: `google-cloud` is deprecated, you shouldn't be trying to install it.

Comment: Okay, does this change the import statement at all?

Comment: This is the tutorial I'm going off of which uses everything I have been doing: https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-client-libraries

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud'

To solve this problem:

1. Remove google-cloud: `pip uninstall google-cloud`
2. Reinstall with update google-cloud-texttospeech: `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-texttospeech`

The library `google-cloud` is deprecated. Do not install this library or use it.

Example code to get you started with Text to Speech:

```
from google.cloud import texttospeech

# Instantiates a client
client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()

# Set the text input to be synthesized
synthesis_input = texttospeech.types.SynthesisInput(text="Hello, World!")

# Build the voice request, select the language code ("en-US") and the ssml
# voice gender ("neutral")
voice = texttospeech.types.VoiceSelectionParams(
    language_code='en-US',
    ssml_gender=texttospeech.enums.SsmlVoiceGender.NEUTRAL)

# Select the type of audio file you want returned
audio_config = texttospeech.types.AudioConfig(
    audio_encoding=texttospeech.enums.AudioEncoding.MP3)

# Perform the text-to-speech request on the text input with the selected
# voice parameters and audio file type
response = client.synthesize_speech(synthesis_input, voice, audio_config)

# The response's audio_content is binary.
with open('output.mp3', 'wb') as out:
    # Write the response to the output file.
    out.write(response.audio_content)
    print('Audio content written to file "output.mp3"')
```

Comment: There is a typo :), anyways your reply helped a lot, thanks.
Should be pip install --upgrade google-cloud-texttospeech

Comment: @NirdeshDwa - Thank you. I fixed the typo in my answer.

Comment: The command `pip uninstall google-cloud` has now run for 2 hours and it's still running. Should this uninstall take this long?

Comment: @Parseval No, it should not. Also do not ask new questions on old posts. Create a new post.

Answer (score 4):

pip3 install google-cloud-bigquery

this worked for me

Comment: Thank you, this command coupled with what was mentioned here helped me resolve my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50841078/2023715