# Python program runs through sublime but not command line

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am attempting to make a web app with flask, and when I attempt to run my script through the command line, I get a "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud'". However, when I run the script in Sublime, I do not get this error.

I have already attempted installing google, google-cloud, and conda using pip.

Here are the lines that are involved in importing from google.cloud. The console states that the first line is the one the compilation is failing at.

```
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types
```

I was expecting the code to be output to my localhost, but this compile time error is preventing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library|package that you need is called `google-cloud-vision`, see:

https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-vision/

You could add this directly to your project (at its current version) using:

```
pip install "google-cloud-vision==0.36.0"
```

However...
Your problem may be a consequence of different python environments and I encourage you to review virtualenv:

https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/

Among other things, `virtualenv` enables (a) the creation of isolated python environments; (b) "clean room" like behavior wherein you can recreate python environments easily and predictably. This latter benefit may help with your "it works .... but doesn't work ... " issue.

One additional good practice, with|without `virtualenv` is to persist `pip install ...` to (conventionally) `requirements.txt`:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

And, in this case, to have `requirements.txt` similar to:

```
flask==1.0.2
google-cloud-vision==0.36.0
```

Comment: I did try your suggestion to use "pip install "google-cloud-vision==0.36.0", however, the problem continues to persist. Also, I am currently using a virtual environment for this project.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if this is relevant, but when I did "pip install "google-cloud-vision==0.36.0", the console gave this error: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\<Name>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ke726vww\googleapis-common-protos\

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54836800/609290. You'd mentioned installing `google-cloud` but you should not use that library. Try to uninstall that and try again.

Comment: Yes, the error you received is relevant. You may wish to try upgrading setuptools and trying that again: `pip install --upgrade setuptools`

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It is working now.